# how to hide div with iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, dopostback

Tricky one here.

The concept is as follows:
on button click I call a javascript function to (dynamically) create a div (`#MainDiv`), then inside the div add an iframe which loads a local page. (This works fine)

in the child page(iframe), I have two buttons; 
`Button1` does some client-side processing then calls `__doPostBack` to activate the server-side `OnClick` method, 
in the server-side method after all processing is done - I registers a javascript block to call a function from the parent page (lets call it "`window.parent.hidediv()`") to remove the `div(#MainDiv.remove())`.

Button2 (Close) just calls the parent function to remove the div (lets call it "`window.parent.hidediv()`")

Button2 works fine - div is removed successfully

The issue:
Button1 on the other hand, all works well until `__doPostBack` is called. the `parent(window.parent.hidediv())` function is called accordingly but for some odd reason the div is not removed (passes `#MainDiv.remove()`, but doesn't do anything)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your actual code responsible for removing div. And also show how do you call that remove div code

Comment: We need some code! Looks like after the postback you are not setting the events to the inner iframe buttons! Then, when you click, nothing happens!

Comment: Okay, I finally managed to get it working. it seems like after postback the iframe was still locked and could not allow the parent div to be removed from the DOM.

So I had to first unload the iframe:

    $('#myiframe').attr("src", "about:blank");

Only after this line can I remove the parent div.

    $("#myparentdiv").remove();